# ASP.Net Download file to client browser

Tags: asp.net, browser, download, response.write

I'm writing a simple test page to download a text file from a browser on button click.  I am getting a really strange error that I have never seen before.  Any thoughts?

The error occurs on `Response.End();` and the file never gets to the client browser

Code:

```
  string filePath = "C:\\test.txt";
  FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);
  if (file.Exists)
  {
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
    Response.End();
  }
```

Error:

> Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.

Comment: remove the end, and try the Responce.Flush() and the Responce.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

Comment: Good call, that stopped the exception from being thrown.  But the code still completes without anything happening on the browser.  ??

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try changing it to.

```
 Response.Clear();
 Response.ClearHeaders();
 Response.ClearContent();
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
 Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
 Response.Flush();
 Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
 Response.End();
```

Comment: Same as before, runs through the code and throws an exception on Response.End().  It seems weird that Response.TransmitFile executes ok but the file does not get transfered?

Comment: @Ashwin: I'm trying this solution in my code-behind file (my issue is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599735/downloading-a-dynamic-file), but no matter where I attempt to call `TransmitFile()` or `WriteFile()` I keep getting an exception: **Server cannot set content type after HTTP headers have been sent.** Any suggestions?

Comment: Response.End() throws an exception by nature.

Comment: This worked for our application which uses this method to allow users to download .svg files.

Comment: `Response.Clear();` does the [same as](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9044607/641833) `Response.ClearContent();`  Why have both?

Comment: Can this be done with with a filestream?  The user chooses the save location and then we stream the file to that location?

Comment: how to use this in a asp webapi?

Answer (score 8):

Just a slight addition to the above solution if you are having problem with downloaded file's name...

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.Name + "\"");
```

This will return the exact file name even if it contains spaces or other characters.