# Response.Clear and Response.ClearContent in Spring MVC

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, spring-mvc

I am need to know what is Response.Clear and Response.ClearContent in  Spring MVC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Response.Clear()` calls `Response.ClearContent()` (just a more matching name for the same function). There is no difference. Both clear the response stream except header infos.

```
public void Clear ()
{
  ClearContent ();
}

public void ClearContent ()
{
  output_stream.Clear ();
  content_length = -1;
}
```

Comment: FROM MSDN, The ClearContent method does not clear header information.

Comment: @user960567 According to MSDN, the `Response.Clear()` method also does not clear header information, so there is no difference there.