# Download File to Client Browser, stuck at Response.End()

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, download

Based on this : [ASP.Net Download file to client browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897458/asp-net-download-file-to-client-browser)

This should also work : ( `contenu` is a string )

```
        Response.Clear();

        Response.ClearHeaders();

        Response.ClearContent();

        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + txtFileName.Value.ToString() + "\"");

        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", contenu.Length.ToString());

        Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

        Response.Flush();

        Response.Write(contenu);

        Response.End();
```

However, after `Response.End()` the browser seems to react because i see it working, but then nothing happens...

Same for Chrome and Explorer.

What should i do ?

Comment: I suspect it may also be something to do with the order of Flush and Write; try swapping their execution ordder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code which has slightly different parameters set; It is working for me

```
protected void ExportData(string fileName, string fileType, string content)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Server.UrlPathEncode(fileName));
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = fileType;
        Response.Output.Write(content);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();

    }
```

Call like this

```
ExportData("Report.txt", "text/plain", yourContentString);
```

Comment: Ok, i just saw i got fooled by the postbacks : after the function, an accidental postback occurs, so headers where sent but then ignored because of page reload, noob mistake, anyway your function is rock solid so i'll accept your answer